# Fire AngularJS after loading an Express-routed Partial

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

i'm still new to AngularJS, and so i encountered a problem that is taking my sleep away ;)...

We have built an app based on node.js and express. The whole routing of the partials is done via Express.

So now, what seemingly happens is:
When i load a new partial angularJS is already fired and does not parse the new content.

Is there a way to tell angular to parse the new content?

I have no good example so far, for it would be incredibly hard to me, to reduce our structure to a "minimal" example.

Anyways, i hope someone has a useful hint ;)

**UPDATE**:

Okay so seemingly it is not only that my app wouldn't run inside-- the partial, but the whole angularJS doesn't work. That means that even if i write something like

```
{{ 1 + 2 }}
```

it will not render as "3", but as {{ 1 + 2 }}. So what i have is a function called "startup()" which calls every function, that i need inside the partials.
I have rewritten my angular-functionality now, so it is an app now.

What i did now is something like suggested from materik inside my startup-function.
Unfortunately this doesn't work too (yes i have implemented the "angular-routes.js)

So just to make clear what seemingly happens:
First load:

- 1) Express loads the "main site as a whole with all things needed (Including Angular)
- 2) I click a link loading a new partial
- 3) Partial-Routing via Express is done, but since it is asynchronus the partial isn't there when angular fires
- 4) expressions do not render and are displayed as {{ expression }}
- 5) If i reload the whole page (by hitting F5) there is no change since first the routing of the "outside" page (everything "above" the partials, where angular works) is done, then, since the URL is something like localhost/someURL express routes as defined for "/someURL" but as angular is already fired it doesn't parse the content inside the partial

So what i need tell angular is something like: "Dear Angular, please wait until the new partial is loaded, then fire"

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to say without seeing any code but I seem to have had a similar problem with my angularjs-node.js-express app where my partials wouldn't update. I solved it by adding this to the frontend code:

```
myAngularApp.run(function($route) {
    $route.reload()
})
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: By now it doesn't seem to work yet. This might be because of the fact that i only did use angular in it's very basic functionality.
There is no "angular-app" so far, all i used until now were some data bindings and one function at the end of the body, which get's a JSON file.
To sum up, what we have is:
1) ng-app initialized in the html-tag
2) one controller, called fetchJSON to read some content out of a JSON-File
3) some {{ expression }}-stuff and ng-repeat throughout the content

There is no real app made yet.

But thanks for the advice, maybe this leads to the right track ;)

Comment: @bquarta did you figure out the issue?